# compare a element from a collection and set it to be last element of that collection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, arraylist, collections

How to achieve:

compare a element from a collection (don't know the index, so can use contains/equals to compare string value), check if exist then have to add some characters to that string value (will be picked up from somewhere else) and then add it back to the collection be be the last element.

Example scenario:

```
xyz<Collection> contains these values:
"abc"
"hgj"
"jsh"
"yjk"

if (xyz.contains("jsh")){
then concat "jsh" + " " + randomOtherStuff
And put it back in the collection to be last element so when printed the order is 
"abc"
"hgj"
"yjk"
"jsh + " " + randomOtherStuff"
}
```

Thank you for all help, in advance :D

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Collections.binarySearch(xyz, "jsh") will return the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (collection.contains("jsh")) {
  collection.remove("jsh"); // remove it, so it can be re-added to the end
  collection.add("jsh " + "asdfgdfgsdfhsjdfh"); // add the new string + some random stuff to the end of the list
}
```

Comment: This of course assumes that it's a collection type that defines the ordering such that it has a last item, and that it's a collection type where `add` is defined such that it gets added to the end when it's added to the collection.  Some of the built in `Collection` classes work this way, and some don't.